# Why is bash broken pipe error generally silent?

Tags: bash, pipe, sh, posix

For example, I have

```
cat file | head -n 2
```

where `file` is very large. This is a broken pipe error since the reader terminates early while the writer still has stuff to write.

However, the output on terminal is just that of `head -n 2` and there is no indication of a broken pipe error. Why is it silent like this and when can I expect to see and be affected by a broken pipe error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the `cat` program doesn't do any special handling of the `SIGPIPE` signal, so the default signal "disposition" (or action) applies. The default action for `SIGPIPE` is "Term", i.e. the program is simply terminated (see the [`signal` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), especially the "Standard signals" section).

One thing that man page doesn't mention is that the terminate action will exit the process with status 128+signal number. `SIGPIPE` is signal 13, so it'll exit with status 141:

```
$ cat /dev/random | head -n1 >/dev/null
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
141 0
```

If a program prints an error message in response to `SIGPIPE`, that's because that program set up a handler for that signal, and it's the handler printing that message. Silence is the default.